# iOS UIImageView constraint not working in table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, nslayoutconstraint

I have implemented a table view cell with an `UIImageView` inside.
A constraint of `width` and `height` has been applied to the `UIImageView`   in the storyboard. However, when I scroll the table view, the image is resized to a bigger size (image original size).

Here is the demo: 
(When an image is scrolled out of the viewport and it disappears and then reappears, the image is resized. The constraint is not working.)

[image: Demo]

Comment: what is the imageview's `contentMode` property set to? try `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`...

Comment: The image view is already in UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Comment: would you like to share your project? are you sure you are using your custom imageview and not the tableviewcell's imageview property?

Answer (score 1):

1. set contentMode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit
2. set clipToBounds to true

Comment: Tested, it's still the same.

Comment: have you set translatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints = false ?

Comment: Yes, cell.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is false